# R:intersection of matrices

Tags: r, set

I was expecting this a simple task but to my surprise I am unable to find the solution of this.

I have to perform set operations on matrices. **Intersect** functions working fine for vectors. But for matrices they consider each column as vector as well.  I need result on row - row comparison instead of each element of matrix.

Consider two following matrices

```
> m1
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
[3,]    3    8
[4,]    4    9
[5,]    5   10
```

and

```
> m2
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    3    8
[3,]    4    9
[4,]    5   10
[5,]    6   11
```

Is there any way to take intersection of both matrices so output must return only first row?

Comment: I don't think *intersection* is the right term given your expected output. Maybe *matching* rows? Also, make it clear that `m1` and `m2` have the same dimensions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most efficient approach (IMHO) is to do:

If you want to compare row `i` to row `i` (what I wouldn't call *intersection*):

```
m1[rowSums(m1 == m2) == ncol(m1), , drop = FALSE]
```

If you want to compare row `i` to any row `j` (what I would call *intersection*):

```
m3 <- rbind(m1, m2)
m3[duplicated(m3), , drop = FALSE]
```

This last one assumes that `m1` and `m2` are sets, i.e. collections of *distinct* items. If it is not the case, you can make them into sets by passing them through `unique`: `m3 <- rbind(unique(m1), unique(m2))`.

Both will be a lot faster than using `apply`.

Comment: thanks! I adopted similar approach to find difference i.e. E1-E2 must returns only rows exists only E1 but not in E2. But duplicate is not much helpful for this. any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
m1[apply(m1==m2, 1, all),]
```

for *paired* comparisons; and this:

```
o <- outer(seq_len(nrow(m1)), seq_len(nrow(m2)), Vectorize(
    function(i, j) all(m1[i,]==m2[j,])
))
m1[apply(o, 1, any),]
m2[apply(o, 2, any),]
```

for all rows in `m1` (resp. `m2`) that are equal to some other row in `m2` (resp. `m1`).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just want row-to-row comparison.
In which case, you can use

```
 m1[m1==m2, ]
```

If you want to compare across all rows, use something like

```
 m1[apply(m1, 1, function(r) any(ncol(m2)==rowSums(r==m2))), ]
```